# Get cursor coordinates in raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

How to get mouse cursor coordinates in raphaeljs library?

I'm trying something like:

```
rect.mousemove(function (event) {
        thisGrid.Popup.Show(event.layerX, event.layerY, ["clientX:", event.clientX, " clientY:", event.clientY, "\n", "layerX:", event.layerX, "layerY:", event.layerY, "\n",
            "pageX:", event.pageX, "pageY:", event.pageY].join(' '));

                        }
                    );
```

But all this properties return coordinates relative left upper corner of window or something.

Here is screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I too had this issue a while back. You need to take into account the current div. In my case the div was called canvas. For the co-ordinates I used the following:

```
posx = e.pageX - $(document).scrollLeft() - $('#canvas').offset().left;
posy = e.pageY - $(document).scrollTop() - $('#canvas').offset().top;
```

**Note:** I was also using jQuery too hence the use of $. You can use document.getElementById if you prefer not to use jQuery.

Comment: it'd be super nice if Raphael just calculated these points (ie relative to Raphael.paper coordinates) and added them to the event object.

Answer (score 9):

If you want coordinates relative to your div, try to use event.offsetX/offsetY

Comment: This worked for me, while the accepted answer (and several variations) did not. Event.offsetX is exactly in the coordinate system Raphael is using for drawing.  (My div height and width match my Raphael init height and width -- I haven't tested whether that is part of why it works.)

Comment: In firefox event does not have offsetX, offsetY, but has layerX and layerY

Answer (score -1):

compute with position of event source element (event.srcElement)

Comment: But event doesnt contain srcElement property. Event has originalTarget CurrentTarget and something. I donnt know how to get targets coordinates. I think should be easy way to do that stuff.

Comment: srcElement is native js property of event object. Find equivalent in jquery

Comment: what is rect? how r u assigning it?